# Music note interval trainer

Tags: java, music

This gives you one note and asks you go up or down the scale for a certain number:

```
///////////////////////////////
//// ClearConsole.java
///////////////////////////////


/**
 * Created by IDEA on 06/12/14.
 */
public final class ClearConsole {
    static void clear() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%n"));
        }
        String s = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////
//// Note.java
///////////////////////////////


import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.lang.Math.abs;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 06/12/14.
 */
public class Note {
    public final static int octaveNumber = 7;
    public final static int totalNotes = 14;
    public final static String[] lowNotes   = {"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"};
    public final static String[] hightNotes = {"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a", "b"};
    public final static String[] notes = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(lowNotes), Arrays.stream(hightNotes)).toArray(size -> new String[size]);
    private String note;
    public static BiMap<String, Integer> noteMap = HashBiMap.create();
    public static BiMap<Integer, String> numberMap;

    static {
        for(int i=0; i<notes.length; i++){
            noteMap.put(notes[i], new Integer(i));
        }
        numberMap = noteMap.inverse();
    }

    public Note(String note) throws Exception {
        if(!ArrayUtils.contains(notes, note)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid note");
        }
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Note(int number) throws Exception {
        this(notes[number]);
    }

    public Note() throws Exception {
        this("C");
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return noteMap.get(note).intValue();
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public boolean isHigh() {
        return ArrayUtils.contains(hightNotes, note) ? true : false;
    }

    // go up or down the scale by a number
    public Note add(int number) throws Exception {
        if(this.isHigh() && number > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can only add to low notes (ABCDEFG)");
        }
        if(!this.isHigh() && number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can only subtract from notes (abcdefg)");
        }
        if(abs(number) > octaveNumber) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Maximum amount of increase or decrease is %d", octaveNumber));
        }

        int newNumber = getNumber() + number;
        return new Note(newNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Note('%s')", note);
    }


    // test
//    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//        Note n1 = new Note("A");
//        Note n2 = n1.add(3);
//        Note n3 = new Note(13);
//        Note n4 = n3.add(-7);
//        System.out.println(n1);
//        System.out.println(n2);
//        System.out.println(n3);
//        System.out.println(n4);
//    }

}

///////////////////////////////
//// Sheet.java
///////////////////////////////


import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 06/12/14.
 */
public class Sheet {
    private final static int lineLength = 70;
    private final static int extraLineLength = 35;
    private final static int notePos = 18;
    private static String line;
    private static String space;
    private static String extraLine;
    private static String extraSpace;
    private List<String> template = initTemplate();
    private List<String> sheet;

    private static List<String> initTemplate() {
        StringBuilder sb1, sb2;
        sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<lineLength; i++) {
            sb1.append("—");
            sb2.append(" ");
        }
        line = sb1.toString();
        space = sb2.toString();
        extraLine = line.substring(0, extraLineLength);
        extraSpace = space.substring(0, extraLineLength);

        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(extraSpace);
        res.add(extraLine);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            res.add(space);
            res.add(line);
        }
        res.add(extraSpace);
        res.add(extraLine);
        return res;
    }

    public Sheet() {
        reset();
    }

    public Sheet annotate(Note note, String annotation) {
        // music notes go from bottom to top, strings are printed from top to bottom
        int index = 13 - note.getNumber();
        String annotatedRow = sheet.get(index);
        annotatedRow = annotatedRow.substring(0, notePos) + annotation + annotatedRow.substring(notePos+annotation.length());
        sheet.set(index, annotatedRow);
        return this;
    }

    public Sheet annotate(Note note) {
        annotate(note, note.getNote());
        return this;
    }

    public void reset() {
        sheet = new ArrayList<>(template);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        sheet.add(0, extraLine);
        return Joiner.on(System.lineSeparator()).join(sheet) + System.lineSeparator();
    }

//    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//        Sheet s = new Sheet();
//        s.annotate(new Note("b"));
//        s.annotate(new Note("G"), "?");
//        System.out.println(s);
//    }

}

///////////////////////////////
//// Trainer.java
///////////////////////////////


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 06/12/14.
 */
public class Trainer {
    private final Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
    private Note note1;
    private Note note2;
    private final Random rand = new Random();
    private int nTry = 0;
    private int nCorrect = 0;
    private int intervalNumber;

//    public Trainer() throws Exception {
//        rand = new Random();
//    }

    public void update() throws Exception {
        intervalNumber = rand.nextInt(Note.octaveNumber) + 1;
        int noteNumber = rand.nextInt(Note.totalNotes);
        note1 = new Note(noteNumber);
        if(note1.isHigh()) {
            intervalNumber = -intervalNumber;
        }
        note2 = note1.add(intervalNumber);
    }

    public String countString() {
        return String.format("[ %d / %d ]%n%n", nCorrect, nTry);
    }

    public String mathQuizString() {
        return String.format("%s + (%d) = ?", note1.getNote(), intervalNumber);
    }

    public String mathRevealString() {
        return String.format("%s + (%d) = %s", note1.getNote(), intervalNumber, note2.getNote());
    }

    public String quizString() {
        sheet.reset();
        return countString() + sheet.annotate(note1).annotate(note2, "?").toString() + System.lineSeparator() + mathQuizString();
    }

    public String revealString() {
        sheet.reset();
        return countString() + sheet.annotate(note1).annotate(note2).toString() + System.lineSeparator() + mathRevealString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            trainer.update();
            ClearConsole.clear();
            System.out.println(trainer.quizString());
            System.out.print("Your answer (type 'quit' shut me down): ");
            String ans = reader.readLine();
            ans = ans.trim();

            if(ans.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            trainer.nTry++;
            ClearConsole.clear();
            if(ans.toLowerCase().equals(trainer.note2.getNote().toLowerCase())) {
                trainer.nCorrect++;
                System.out.println(trainer.revealString());
                System.out.printf("You answer is %s, your are right.%nPress enter to continue.", ans);
            } else {
                System.out.println(trainer.revealString());
                System.out.printf("You answer is %s, your are wrong.%nPress enter to continue.", ans);
            }
            ans = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- I find this to be an effective, but smelly way to clear the console:

  > ```
  > public final class ClearConsole {
  >     static void clear() {
  >         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  >         for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  >             stringBuilder.append(String.format("%n"));
  >         }
  >         String s = stringBuilder.toString();
  >         System.out.println(s);
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

  There are [better ways to go about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015039/3198973).
- [The real musical scale has half-steps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note#Accidentals). This code ignores that.
- Looks like you've got a typo here:

  > ```
  > hightNotes
  > ```